# Is it legal for a C compiler to optimize out local static variables?

Tags: c, static, local, compiler-optimization

For a function like

```
int test(void) {
  static int x = 0;
  x++;
  return 0;
}
```

is a C compiler allowed to optimize out `x`?

For reference, neither GCC 6.3.0 or Clang 3.9 optimize out incrementing `x` with -O3.

Comment: Like.. Why not?

Comment: Even with optimisations enabled?

Comment: So, what about the _observable behaviour_ changed?

Comment: That's it, I think the compiler is allowed to do just anything given the observable behavior is identical (given the code is not invoking undefined behavior).

Comment: What about visibility of `x` within the data section of the program and within symbol tables? Do the C specs have anything to say about that?

Comment: The C standard has nothing to say about e.g. symbol tables, as they're an implementation detail.  However, the scope of x is only that function.

Comment: @EricMartin C standard is not operating in these terms.

Comment: @yellowantphil - The compiler can assume that undefined behavior never happens. And gcc is known to optimize on that assumption.

Comment: When I compile this on Windows' Ubuntu's gcc 4.8.4 with just main calling this function it actually optimizes out the whole function call, sets return value and hapily returns

Answer (score 2):

The compiler would be within its rights to optimise away this function completely, given it has no observable side effects (from the point of view of the C standard).

As to why your compilers aren't doing so, I can't explain that!  (Though of course, they're under no obligation to do so.)